# Average of points

Tags: average

I am teaching a year 8 class data, and they came across this question which they didn't know how to do.

The question is: Annie averages 15 points per game for the first 3 games of the AFL season. Over the next two weeks she scores 18 and 22 points. Find her average score over the 5 games?

This is my working

Find the average of the next 2 games
$$\frac {(18+22)}{2} = 20$$

I then find the average of the 2 averages
$$\frac {(15+20)}{2}= 17.5$$

Because you can't have an average of 17.5 points, would you round up or down?

Comment: So, the question is all about [rounding off numbers](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://academic.brooklyn.cuny.edu/geology/leveson/core/linksa/roundoff.html&ved=2ahUKEwiw6v31vqbrAhUqzjgGHeIAA4UQFjAKegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw3-VCAlaQI7ZW-lP6HJqTX_).

Comment: You cannot average averages as you do. What if there were 2 million games in the first batch, with average score 0 ? Then playing an additional 2 games (with scores 1 and 1) makes the total average 2/2000002, not 1/2.

Comment: The average of averages isn't the average. Imagine scoring $1$ point a game for $100$ games and than $3$ points in the next game. Is your average $2$? What you need is $\frac{15\cdot 3+18+22}{5}=17=\frac{\textrm{total points}}{\textrm{total games}}$.

Comment: p.s. its good to see a fellow Australian on here

Comment: Also, it makes perfect sense to have a noninteger average. You should not round to an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, taking an average of an average won't provide an accurate picture of the average score over five games.

Let's say Annie scores exactly $15$ points in each of her first three games (providing an average of $15$). Her average score over the five games would be

$$\frac{15+15+15+18+22}{5}=17$$

though it doesn't matter what combination you use to get an average of $15$; you will always have a five-game average of $17$ (i.e. having $14$ points, then $15$, then $16$ would still give you an average score over five games of $17$).